# one in one out requirement vs uniform waiters requirement in multi threading java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

What are following terms while explaining Bounded buffer example in multi threading:

1.one-in, one-out requirement

2.uniform waiters requirement

I have seen following statement in book [java concurrency in practice](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=fv4tEfwgcjsC&pg=PA303&lpg=PA303&dq=BoundedBuffer%20meets%20the%20one-in,%20one-out%20requirement,%20but%20does%20not%20meet%20the%20uniform%20waiters%20requirement%20because%20waiting%20threads%20might%20be%20waiting%20for%20either%20the%20%E2%80%9Cnot%20full%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9Cnot%20empty%E2%80%9D%20condition.&source=bl&ots=bE96oHA77E&sig=TWRpCV2Yurh2Ps0DF94wmn3u05k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB2NfD-LTOAhVMOo8KHSFcD0UQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=BoundedBuffer%20meets%20the%20one-in%2C%20one-out%20requirement%2C%20but%20does%20not%20meet%20the%20uniform%20waiters%20requirement%20because%20waiting%20threads%20might%20be%20waiting%20for%20either%20the%20%E2%80%9Cnot%20full%E2%80%9D%20and%20%E2%80%9Cnot%20empty%E2%80%9D%20condition.&f=false)

```
BoundedBuffer meets the one-in, one-out requirement, but does not meet the uniform waiters requirement because waiting threads might be waiting for either the “not full” and “not empty” condition.
```

Can someone explain me the two terms and their difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These terms refer to threads that `wait()` on an arbitrary monitor:

- *uniform waiters*: waiting threads are "equal", i.e. they wait for the same condition to become true.
- *one-in, one-out*: a notification on the condition allows at most one thread to proceed.

You should only use `notify()` when both properties are met, otherwise invoke `notifyAll()` (though it's less efficient).

Goetz explains this on page 303 and gives two concrete examples:

> `BoundedBuffer` meets the one-in, one-out requirement, but does not meet the uniform waiters requirement *because waiting threads might be waiting for either the "not full"* [producers block on put] *and "not empty"* [consumers block on take] *condition"*. A "starting gate" latch […] in which a single event releases a set of threads, does not meet the one-in, one-out requirement *because opening the starting gate lets multiple threads proceed*.

You can also demonstrate this using classes from [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html):

```java
BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);

new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1L);
        System.out.println("Producer starts.");
        queue.put("foo");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* NOP */ }
}).start();

try {
    System.out.println("Consumer starts.");
    System.out.println(queue.take());
} catch (InterruptedException e) { /* NOP */ }
```

The consumer has to wait until the producer puts `"foo"` into the queue. Both wait for different conditions, hence, a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) doesn't meet the uniform waiters requirement.

On the other hand, a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) meets the uniform waiters requirement, but doesn't meet the one-in, one-out requirement. Once the latch reaches zero, all waiting threads are released:

```java
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
Runnable r = () -> {
    try {
        latch.await();
        System.out.println("Thread proceeds.");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { /* NOP */ }
};

new Thread(r).start();
new Thread(r).start();

try {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1L);
    System.out.println("Count down.");
    latch.countDown();
} catch (InterruptedException e) { /* NOP */ }
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that `ReentrantLock` lets you have "uniform waiters" in many cases where `synchronized` does not.  E.g., if you use a `ReentrantLock` to guard a blocking queue, you can have one `Condition` for the producers, and a separate `Condition` for the consumers even though there is only one `Lock` for the whole queue.

Comment: @jameslarge Sure, if you mixup components with different concurrency semantics, things get complicated. ;)